# Unable to run terraform from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

My Project is to launch instances on AWS using terraform script, the script is running well in local, i want to automate the process through jenkins and i put the code in git, below is the pipeline script i used in jenkins

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    tools {
        terraform 'terraform'
    }
     stages{
        stage('Git Checkout'){
            steps{
                git credentialsId: 'git credentials id', url: 'https://gitlab.com/ndey1/kafka-infra'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Terraform init'){
            steps{
                sh 'terraform init'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Terraform apply'){
            steps{
                sh 'terraform apply --auto approve'
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

but getting the error in jenkins

```
Started by user Company
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/infra-kaka
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Tool Install)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Git Checkout)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] git
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential "credential id"
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://gitlab.com/ndey1/kafka-infra
 > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/infra-kaka # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://gitlab.com/ndey1/kafka-infra
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.25.1'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://gitlab.com/ndey1/kafka-infra +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url https://gitlab.com/ndey1/kafka-infra # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Avoid second fetch
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Terraform init)
Stage "Terraform init" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Terraform apply)
Stage "Terraform apply" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Terraform already installed in system, also all plugin updated

Comment: You have an error in the `--auto approve`, it should be `-auto-approve`: https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/apply.html#automatic-plan-mode.

Comment: If you read the log it says that it skipped them  because of a previous error - they didn't fail, they never ran... At the end of the logs it says that it can't find the revision in the git repo to build.

Comment: yeah but "main" branch is there and is there any problem in this line : stages{
        stage('Git Checkout'){
            steps{
                git credentialsId: 'credential id', url: 'https://gitlab.com/ndey1/kafka-infra'
            }
        }

Comment: @fredrik That is true, but even if it did get to the apply stage it would have failed because of wrongly defined auto approve.

Comment: @NiladriDey I would probably add a dir step and set it to `kafka-infra`, i.e., `dir("kafka-infra")` and then follow up with the shell command for terraform init. I would do the same for the second stage also.

Comment: @fredrik I have changed the auto-approve but still its unable to fetch from git ... not sure why

Comment: @MarkoE I have tried even that also https://gitlab.com/ndey1/dir("kafka-infra") but getting error Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://gitlab.com/ndey1/dir("kafka-infra") +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/ndey1/dir("kafka-infra")/': The requested URL returned error: 503.      actually in in the repo there are 2 directories 1) terraform 2) ansible...

Comment: That is not how it works. You need to have a `dir` inside the `steps` section, before calling `terraform init`. So something like:

steps {
        script {
          dir("kafka-infra") {
               sh "terraform init"
          }
        }
      }

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix, I used following lines in stage

```
stages{
        stage('Git Checkout'){
            steps{
                git branch: 'main', credentialsId: 'gitlab id', url: 'https://gitlab.com/ndey1/kafka-infra'
            }
        }
```

It is able to fetch now